# can't run a binary compiled with -race on our production infrastructure

Tags: go, race-detector

I tried running a golang binary compiled with the -race flag on a server, and got the following error:

```
fatal error: too many address space collisions for -race mode

runtime stack:
runtime.throw({0x18c0323?, 0xfffff?})
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:1077 +0x5c fp=0x73783ad4f608 sp=0x73783ad4f5d8 pc=0x4731bc
runtime.(*mheap).sysAlloc(0x2769760, 0x689f9dc00000?, 0x2779928, 0x1)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/malloc.go:683 +0x685 fp=0x73783ad4f6a0 sp=0x73783ad4f608 pc=0x4475c5
runtime.(*mheap).grow(0x2769760, 0x689f9dbff580?)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mheap.go:1483 +0x73 fp=0x73783ad4f710 sp=0x73783ad4f6a0 pc=0x464493
runtime.(*mheap).allocSpan(0x2769760, 0x1, 0x0, 0xe8?)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mheap.go:1250 +0x1b0 fp=0x73783ad4f7b0 sp=0x73783ad4f710 pc=0x463d70
[...]
```

Any idea on how this can happen ?

---

More details:

```
# the complete stack trace:
runtime.(*mheap).alloc.func1()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mheap.go:968 +0x5c fp=0x73783ad4f7f8 sp=0x73783ad4f7b0 pc=0x4637fc
runtime.(*mheap).alloc(0x2780160?, 0x274e720?, 0x19?)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mheap.go:962 +0x5b fp=0x73783ad4f840 sp=0x73783ad4f7f8 pc=0x46375b
runtime.(*mcentral).grow(0x73783ad4f8c0?)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mcentral.go:246 +0x52 fp=0x73783ad4f880 sp=0x73783ad4f840 pc=0x451e52
runtime.(*mcentral).cacheSpan(0x277aea8)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mcentral.go:166 +0x306 fp=0x73783ad4f8d8 sp=0x73783ad4f880 pc=0x451cc6
runtime.(*mcache).refill(0x689f9e4c0108, 0x0?)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mcache.go:182 +0x153 fp=0x73783ad4f918 sp=0x73783ad4f8d8 pc=0x451413
runtime.(*mcache).nextFree(0x689f9e4c0108, 0x1c)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/malloc.go:925 +0x85 fp=0x73783ad4f960 sp=0x73783ad4f918 pc=0x447745
runtime.mallocgc(0xc0, 0x1656b60, 0x1)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/malloc.go:1112 +0x448 fp=0x73783ad4f9e0 sp=0x73783ad4f960 pc=0x447d08
runtime.newobject(0x73783ad4f9f8?)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/malloc.go:1324 +0x25 fp=0x73783ad4fa08 sp=0x73783ad4f9e0 pc=0x448305
internal/cpu.doinit()
    /usr/local/go/src/internal/cpu/cpu_x86.go:51 +0x1e fp=0x73783ad4fa68 sp=0x73783ad4fa08 pc=0x43b1be
internal/cpu.Initialize({0x0, 0x0})
    /usr/local/go/src/internal/cpu/cpu.go:125 +0x1d fp=0x73783ad4fa88 sp=0x73783ad4fa68 pc=0x43ac1d
runtime.cpuinit({0x0?, 0x800000000?})
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:639 +0x1f fp=0x73783ad4faa8 sp=0x73783ad4fa88 pc=0x476b1f
runtime.schedinit()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:729 +0xbd fp=0x73783ad4faf0 sp=0x73783ad4faa8 pc=0x476d7d
runtime.rt0_go()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:349 +0x11c fp=0x73783ad4faf8 sp=0x73783ad4faf0 pc=0x4a8dfc


# the build environment:

$ uname -r
6.2.0-36-generic
$ go version
go version go1.21.3 linux/amd64
$ go env
GO111MODULE=''
GOARCH='amd64'
GOBIN=''
GOCACHE='/home/builder/.cache/go-build'
GOENV='/home/builder/.config/go/env'
GOEXE=''
GOEXPERIMENT=''
GOFLAGS=''
GOHOSTARCH='amd64'
GOHOSTOS='linux'
GOINSECURE=''
GOMODCACHE='/home/builder/go/pkg/mod'
GONOPROXY=''
GONOSUMDB=''
GOOS='linux'
GOPATH='/home/builder/go'
GOPRIVATE=''
GOPROXY='https://proxy.golang.org,direct'
GOROOT='/usr/local/go'
GOSUMDB='sum.golang.org'
GOTMPDIR=''
GOTOOLCHAIN='auto'
GOTOOLDIR='/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64'
GOVCS=''
GOVERSION='go1.21.3'
GCCGO='gccgo'
GOAMD64='v1'
AR='ar'
CC='gcc'
CXX='g++'
CGO_ENABLED='1'
GOMOD='/opt/workdir/src/go.mod'
GOWORK=''
CGO_CFLAGS='-O2 -g'
CGO_CPPFLAGS=''
CGO_CXXFLAGS='-O2 -g'
CGO_FFLAGS='-O2 -g'
CGO_LDFLAGS='-O2 -g'
PKG_CONFIG='pkg-config'
GOGCCFLAGS='-fPIC -m64 -pthread -Wl,--no-gc-sections -fmessage-length=0 -ffile-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build4196099212=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches'

# the run environment:

# runs on a Linux system with a customized Linux 5.15.28 (customized by our host provider, not by us)
```

Comment: The first result from Google suggest that you can hit this using cgo linking against something compiled with `-fsanitize`, since it uses the same mechanisms as the race detector.

Comment: yes, I also found that link. The only compiler options I see are `GOGCCFLAGS=...`, there isn't a direct mention of `-fsanitize` there, and I don't think any sanitizer is implied by the other options (perhaps someone will tell me otherwise ?).

Comment: I don't mean it's set in your Go flags -- are you using cgo and linking to anything that was already compiled with the address sanitizer?

Comment: @JimB: the system we run on is managed by our host provider, I will ask that. Our binary has pretty standard dependencies (objdump lists `libresolv, libpthread and libc`) so it would be one of those, right ?

Comment: If you're not using cgo for anything specific other than the normal std library usage, you could try to build the binary without it and see if that changes the outcome.

Comment: @JimB: unfortunately that doesn't work with `go build -race` ... :/ which explicitly requires cgo

Comment: could there be a similar behavior built into the kernel ? our servers are managed by our hosting provider, which provides systems with custom kernels, at the moment I don't know the exact options they used when compiling it.

Comment: ah yes, I forgot since that links differently on macOS. You could try `-tags=netgo` (or `GODEBUG=netdns=go` at runtime) to avoid the host resolver, but I'm not sure how else it interacts once linked

Comment: It's also possible this is unrelated to cgo, and you have a different situation. Maybe a huge heap, or virtual memory or something (the race detector does have other limitations, like number of goroutines, but that's a different error)

Comment: where can I read about the toggles that affect the race detector ?

Comment: There are no options for the race detector itself. As for other resources I'm not sure, but the sanitizers repo has some general documentation: https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki